# real life situations using palindrome algorithm

Tags: java

so, for my final project in data  structure class, we are to develop algorithms for  palindrome, but I sorta want to fancy it up a bit and make into a mini program, what real life situation mimic the usage of palindrome,exempt for works on strings, 
thanks !

Comment: Try the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

In real life, could be used for some compression algorithms.

For example there are researches about biological sequence compression algorithms, that use this property

[HERE](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11700586), [HERE](http://www.arpapress.com/volumes/vol9issue3/ijrras_9_3_14.pdf) and [HERE](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397508008852) more details

Answer (score 3):

Palindromes are used in DNA for marking and permitting cutting. They are used to change one dimensional chain into 2 or 3 dimensional structure.

Answer (score 2):

One interesting application of Longest Palindromic Substring aka Manacher's Algorithm that came out of my head is: while playing Indian Rummy card game (aka Rummy 13), if LPS is 5, then the card occuring at the middle of that substring is a great candiadate for next selection to have two rummies. Similarly if LPS is 6, 4 etc has other similar potential.

Example: (Played with more than 1 deck) There are 13 cards out of which 5 cards are as below:
Clubs of 2, 3, 4, 3 2
Let this be the longest palindrome we got out of all 13 cards. Here Middle card is Clubs 4, which is a great candidate to be selected next. 
Because, if in next round you get a Clubs 4, you could have two rummies: 234 and 234.

Comment: this is really interesting, is there any formal research on the topic?

Comment: @yozaam just my experience from playing cards

Answer (score 1):

Palindromes are strings that read the same forwards as backwards such as:

> A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!
>
> Was it Eliot's toilet I saw?
>
> Dennis And Edna Sinned

There aren't many real-world applications for this, and finding Palindromes is fairly specific to Strings... Even numeric palindromes operate on the digits within a String...

ie. 580085

is a numeric palindrome, but would still be found by analysing characters in a String.

However, the skills you get from learning to traverse Strings in reverse, recognise special cases such as shared middle characters, perform case insensitive comparisons and strip out non alphanumeric characters from Strings when performing comparisons are useful to all sorts of real-world applications.

Comment: "...are useful to all sorts of real-world applications.". Well thats the question. Name some applications please

Comment: I'm trying to make the point that the exercise the question asker has been given isn't trying to teach palindromes... it's trying to teach critical thinking and string manipulation. It would be easier to list real world applications that didn't require critical thinking and string manipulation in development than to list those that do.